# how to link antd tabs with antd pagination

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

I am new to react and using antd tabs and pagination, I am trying to link tabs with pagination so that active tab should have the same active number in pagination. Please help me.
Thank you`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'antd';

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
    <Tabs.TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </Tabs.TabPane>
    <Tabs.TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
      Content of Tab Pane 2
    </Tabs.TabPane>
    <Tabs.TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </Tabs.TabPane>
  </Tabs>
);

export default App;
```

```
 <Pagination
// current={current}
// onChange={onChange}
total={30}
 />
```

`

I tried to link the active status of tab to the active status of pagination, but couldn't find.I want when I click on pagination number that current number tab should come into active state

Answer (score 1):

here you are:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { Tabs, Pagination } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(1);

  const onChange = (key: string) => {
    setCurrent(key);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs
        activeKey={current}
        defaultActiveKey={1}
        onChange={onChange}
        items={[
          {
            label: `Tab 1`,
            key: 1,
            children: `Content of Tab Pane 1`,
          },
          {
            label: `Tab 2`,
            key: 2,
            children: `Content of Tab Pane 2`,
          },
          {
            label: `Tab 3`,
            key: 3,
            children: `Content of Tab Pane 3`,
          },
        ]}
      />
      <Pagination
        defaultCurrent={current}
        total={3}
        onChange={onChange}
        pageSize={1}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ehk3bg?file=demo.tsx

Comment: Hi kamran, thanks for your answer, when I click on pagination, tabs are changing, but when I click on tabs page number is not changing